# What determines the dimension used for least squares in GMRES?

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I understand GMRES consists of two phases:

1. determining the vector basis used for least squares (Arnoldi process)
2. applying least squares to this vector basis to find a hopefully better solution

What determines the dimension of the Vector space created in step 1?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.